# Is the spectrum of a nonnegative operator on a real Hilbert space contained in $[0,\infty)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

If $A$ is a bounded *nonnegative* (i.e. $\langle Ax,x\rangle_H\ge0$ for all $x\in H$) linear operator on a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space $H$, are we able to show that the spectrum $\sigma(A)$ of $A$ is contained in $[0,\infty)$?

I know that the claim is true for bounded nonnegative linear operators on **complex** Hilbert spaces, but I wonder whether this might fail to hold in the real case. The situation should be difference, since in the complex setting nonnegativity already implies self-adjointness. But even with the additional assumption of self-adjointness I'm ensure whether there are any issues occurring.

Comment: How do you define $\sigma(A)$?  Is it a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ by definition, or do you complexify and use the usual definition over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @EricWofsey I define $\sigma(A)$ as the complement of the resolvent set which by definition contains all $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ such that $(\lambda-A)^{-1}$ is bounded and densely-defined.

Comment: So, to be sure, by definition $\sigma(A)$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes, it is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.  By scaling $A$, it suffices to show that $-1\not\in\sigma(A)$.  So, suppose $-1\in\sigma(A)$, i.e. $A+I$ is not invertible.  If $A+I$ does not have dense image, let $x$ be a nonzero vector orthogonal to its image and observe that $$\langle Ax,x\rangle=\langle (A+I)x,x\rangle-\langle x,x\rangle=-\langle x,x\rangle<0,$$ a contradiction.  Thus $A+I$ must have dense image.  Since it is not invertible, there must exist unit vectors $x$ such that $(A+I)x$ is arbitrarily small.  In particular, choosing a unit vector $x$ such that $\|(A+I)x\|<1$, we again have $$\langle Ax,x\rangle=\langle (A+I)x,x\rangle-\langle x,x\rangle<0$$ giving a contradiction.